# Effect of previous refusals on UK visit visa?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, tourist-visas, standard-visitor-visas

My application for a standard UK visitor visa was denied, citing lack of sufficient documents for evidence of income (tax returns).

This is understandable, as I've only started to earn significantly since the last 12 months, hence only one year of tax returns was available and the case officer refused to consider my salary bank account statement as the sole evidence of proof of income.

[image]
[image]

So now (2 months after refusal) I wish to reapply for the visa but this time with the entire travel sponsored by my parents. They have sufficient documents to prove their income, property evaluation papers etc.

However the visa application form has a field that asks if my visa to  the UK was ever refused, to which I now have to fill yes.

Q1. How likely is the first refusal going to affect this new application?

The refusal letter I received on my first attempt did mention that all future applications would be considered on their individual merits. But hearing from various sources this is still likely to be false and previous refusal may cause problems.

Q2. Is applying just 2 months after the last refusal too soon. Will it raise eyebrows?

**EDIT**: The refusal letter indicates I did not provide a tax certificate even though I absolutely positive I enclosed it along with my application in the envelope provided to me at the VFS centre. Is it possible that the case officer simply missed that document or didn't bother with it since it was only one year's assessment?

Comment: If you can address the issues they raised in your refusal that impact might be negligible

Comment: You should post the refusal letter with your personal information blanked out. However, you may have been refused for not having a strong reason to return at the end of your visit, and the fact that your parents have property and will pay for your trip wouldn't really change that.

Comment: @user16259 yes, the stated reason was the same "not sufficient reason to return" . But by that logic no unemployed or newly employed individual would ever be eligible for travel to the u.k

Comment: That reason does not correspond with what you have described as the reason. You're looking at the refusal letter the wrong way. If you post it here it will help you get good answers

Comment: @HankyPanky I've added scanned images of relevant parts from the reply. Also I wonder if its appropriate to treat this question as a specific case for this application and discuss more on it or should each question should be its own

Comment: You should contain this application in one question on this site. You could go ahead with a new application as soon as you like, but you should consider getting a professional to help with the next application. You will have to address the issue of them not believing your source of income even if your parents sponsor you.

Answer (score 1):

Your application was rejected essentially because you did not supply enough evidence that your income was really what you had claimed. Your bank statements were not considered enough because the money coming in could have been anything, not necessarily salary, but perhaps loans designed to inflate your bank balance.

What you should have done was to also provide documents showing that this was indeed your income. If your work was done through your own company you should have provided statements or accounts for that company, showing income from customers and payments to you. If there was no company then receipts and invoices from customers, with amounts that matched the money coming in to your account. Also a tax certificate showing that you declared that amount of income to the government. other documents backing up your statements may work too.

In making a second application, the best way to go is to provide all that information to them this time round. This shows that the problem was simply that you omitted to provide the documentation to back up your case. Doing this would give a good chance of success (assuming there are no other problems).

The trouble with making a second application based on your parents paying for everything is that they will wonder why you aren't just providing the documents to back up what you said in your first application. If you have the income to pay for the trip yourself, why get your parents to pay? This will lead them to suspect that you were not in fact telling the truth in the first application, and that suspicion will definitely count against you. Being suspected of deception is one of the surest ways of getting a refusal.

Comment: I see, I did include the tax certificate (for year 1) along with the signed contracts that I was getting paid for but i beleive they simply ignored it because it was not sufficient or verifiable. I'm going to consult with a solicitor about the invoices part

Comment: Does anyone know what a proper payslip sent digitally would look like if its not possible to gather original paper slips? or is this a question for SE legal?

Comment: @Allahjane You should ask a separate question about that. It should be OK on this site if you ask it as "what is acceptable to the UK visa office?"

Comment: So I got it granted this time around , I included all documents I could , including a sponsership/invite  from a UK National and a more concrete reason to visit (attending a bussiness event) along with printed hard copies of all relevant invoices and contracts. For more details please see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107770/are-scanned-and-printed-supporting-documents-accepted-for-uk-visitor-visa/109318#109318